# Mapping in HTML pages

Tags: html, mapping

I used this code in a e-blast of mine. Now I'm faced with a situation where this technique of linking would save me alot of time. In basic HTML websites, Is this a good practice in terms of linking areas of your page to a url?

```
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="90,307,563,370" href=""      
target="_blank">
   <area shape="rect" coords="169,685,500,710" href=""  target="_blank">
   <area shape="rect" coords="146,715,514,738" href="" target="_blank">
   <area shape="rect" coords="347,864,510,901" href="" target="_blank">
   <area shape="rect" coords="246,743,406,764" href="" target="_blank">
</map>
```

Answer (score -1):

**[Imagemaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map)** are old HTML, but there's nothing wrong with them. Still perfectly valid.